# Arch Linux makepkg failed on compressing package

Tags: arch-linux, package-management

I just reinstalled Arch Linux 2010.05 on VPS, and

```
sudo pacman -Syu
```

But when I try to install anything from AUR, makepkg failed on

```
==> Tidying install...
  -> Purging unwanted files...
  -> Compressing man and info pages...
  -> Stripping unneeded symbols from binaries and libraries...
==> Creating package...
  -> Generating .PKGINFO file...
  -> Compressing package...
bsdtar: FIEMAP failed: Invalid argument
bsdtar: FIEMAP failed: Invalid argument
bsdtar: FIEMAP failed: Invalid argument
==> Leaving fakeroot environment.
```

Comment: Are you using an AUR helper? How are you trying to build the package? Are you sure you are up-to-date? Some more information would be helpful...

Answer (score 1):

It's an upstream bug, which I've opened a report for:

http://code.google.com/p/libarchive/issues/detail?id=238

As a temporary workaround, you can build in tmpfs, which won't have this problem.